# How to configure gulp build with tasks.json version 2?

Tags: javascript, gulp, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Right now we are using the tasks.json 0.1.0 version of tasks in Visual Studio Code.

Navigating to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks indicates that VS code will automatically detect all of my tasks in my gulp file.

I've installed various extensions to try and autodetect my tasks and they are still not being detected.

At this point, I'm looking into creating a new version of tasks.json that handles all of our gulp tasks.

How do I do this?  Here is my tasks.json 0.1.0:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "gulp",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": [],
"showOutput": "always",
"options": {
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/MyAppName"
},
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "args": ["build:debug"]
    },
    {
        "taskName": "build:debug",
        "args": ["build:debug"]
    },
    {
        "taskName": "build:release",
        "args": ["build:release"]
    }
]
}
```

I've looked at other questions and there doesn't seem to be anything at the moment that indicates how to get gulp running in tasks.json 2.0.

I want to be able to use this build task from outside of the folder that contains the gulpfile.  I know VS will automatically detect the tasks if the folder where my gulpfile is opened.

Answer (score 0):

After scouring the web, I couldn't find anything.  I wanted to setup a custom build in code for our build:debug gulp task.

So, I built my own:

(buildDebug.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
pwd
cd [your gulpfile.js directory]
gulp build:debug
```

(tasks.json)

```
    {
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Run Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/c/[where you saved buildDebug.sh]/buildDebug.sh",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```